# reloading ember-data models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a controller that reloads data when data is received from a websocket.  I've got it working up to the point of reloading the data.  I'm not sure why this isn't working, but I'm getting an error when I call self.get('contact').reload(); below.  'object has no method reload'.  I'm pretty sure I'm calling this incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to reload the data from the store.  Could someone help me out?

```
CallMonitor.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return  this.store.find('contact');
},
setupController: function(controller, contacts) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    controller.set('socket', socket);
    controller.set('contact', contacts);
}
});

CallMonitor.ContactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
socketDidChange: function(){
    var socket = this.get('socket'),
        self = this;
    if(socket)
    {
        socket.on('call', function (data) {
            var contactToUpdate = self.contact.filter(function(item) {
                return item.id == data.contactId;
            });
            if(contactToUpdate.length)
            {
                contactToUpdate.reload();
            }
            else
            {
                // reload all the contacts
                self.get('contact').reload();
            }
        });
    }
}.observes('socket')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just doing another fetch from the store and then setting the controller's contact property again.  Couldn't find an easy way to do a reload for multiple records.  For single records, it's easy to just do a "reload()" but for new records and such it's apparently not that easy.

```
var contactPromise = self.contact.store.find('contact');
contactPromise.then(function(data){
    self.set('contact', data);
}, undefined);
```

Kind of a bummer.  Also couldn't find a good way to remove records in ember data.